# Typescript conditional types depending on occurrence in dictionary

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, conditional-statements

I'm trying to type a function with a rather complex type signature. It accepts two dictionaries `args` and `funcs`, where `funcs` maps keys to functions that transform type A to B, and `args` maps a superset of those keys to: A if the key occurs in `funcs`, and to B otherwise. I.e., if a function is defined for a certain key, use the function to map the value from the same key from the other dictionary, if no corresponding function exists just use the value itself.

I've got the following so far, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
function foo<Properties>(
  args: { [P in keyof typeof funcs]: Parameters<typeof funcs[P]>[0] } & {
    [P in Exclude<keyof Properties, keyof typeof funcs>]?: Properties[P];
  },
  funcs: { [P in keyof Properties]?: (attributes: any) => Properties[P] }
) {}

interface Bar {
  x: number;
  y: string;
}

foo<Bar>(
  {
    x: "a",
    y: 1,
  },
  {
    y: (a: string) => "a",
  }
);
```

In this case, I would expect to see two errors: one indicating that `x` should map to a `number` in the first dictionary, and the second indicating that `y` should be a `string` in the first dictionary. It seems I'm overestimating the power of TS - is this intended behavior even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem!

I think this achieves your intended outcome:

```
type Func<I, O> = (arg: I) => O
type Funcs<T> = { [K in keyof Partial<T>]: Func<K, T[K]> }

declare function converter<Properties>(
  args: Properties,
  funcs: Funcs<Properties>
): void;

interface Bar {
  x: number;
  y: string;
}

converter<Bar>(
  {
    x: 1,
    y: "foo",
  },
  {
    y: (a: string) => "2",
  }
);
```

Comment: That doesn't quite capture it, consider:
```
converter<Bar>(
    {
      x: "a",
      y: 1,
    },
    {
      x: (a: string) => 1,
      y: (a: number) => "2",
    }
  );
```
In this case, the functions map the inputs to the correct types according to the interface, but both lines are still marked as incorrect. Edit: no multiline support in comments, rip formatting.

Comment: Ah ok. I wasn't clear that the functions had arbitrary return types. Let me have a tweak

Comment: Actually, the return type should be `T[K]`, it's the input type that can be arbitrary - so long as it corresponds to the type of the value in `args` at the same key.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm explaining myself properly, so here's a third attempt. :P Say `Properties` has type `{ x: number }`, then both the following are acceptable call signatures: `converter<Bar>({ x: 1 }, {})` and `converter<Bar>({ x: "some text" }, { x: (str: string) => 1 })`. I.e., the function called with the given value should return the type from the interface if there is a function, if no function exists the value itself should be of type from the interface.

Comment: Ideally, I would have something like: `args: { [K in keyof Properties]?: K in keyof typeof funcs ? Parameters<typeof funcs[K]> : Properties[K] }`, and to have `funcs` use a subset of the keys of `args`. But I can't seem to find out how to do this..

Comment: Ah ok. I don't think what you are after is possible. Sorry...

Comment: To link the type of argument A with the type of argument B, you need to infer the generic type parameter to something more specific. This is doable; but if you want to specify the `Properties` type parameter explicitly, then this breaks down - because TypeScript won't infer *any* type parameters if any are explicitly specified. You need to either supply all or none - this will be a barrier for what you are trying to do I think.